# KERNELBASE.dll error running c# app on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: c#, dllimport, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a .NET 3.5 executable, compiled with 'Any CPU' and when I attempt to run it on Windows Server 2008 x64 R2 - It gives me:

```
Faulting application name: mcb.exe, version: 0.1.0.8, time stamp: 0x4e08e871
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdfe0
```

Has anyone else encountered/solved this issue?

I suspect the DLLImports is that it doesn't even make it to main() --
I should also add that this works fine on non-R2 Win Server 2008 x64

**EDIT**: Nevermind -- the dll import doesn't appear to be the cause of the issue --
I commented it out and tried it, the same behavior occurred.
Renaming question.

**EDIT II**: This kernel base dll error seems to be rather common but I can't find any reason why.

Complete error per request:

```
Faulting application name: mcb.exe, version: 0.1.0.8, time stamp: 0x4e08eb21
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdfe0
Exception code: 0xe0434f4d
Fault offset: 0x000000000000aa7d
Faulting process id: 0x%9
Faulting application start time: 0x%10
Faulting application path: %11
Faulting module path: %12
Report Id: %13
```

I can't attach a debugger in time and cannot install VS on faulting machine :-(

Here is the windbg output, I'm afraid it is just gibberish to me... I don't know if anyone can make sense of it.

```
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00000000`01180000 00000000`0132c000   mcb.exe 
ModLoad: 00000000`77710000 00000000`778bc000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f4dc0000 000007fe`f4e2f000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`775f0000 00000000`7770f000   C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fd8f0000 000007fe`fd95b000   C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
(1870.15fc): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ntdll.dll - 
ntdll!CsrSetPriorityClass+0x40:
00000000`777c0fb0 cc              int     3
0:000> g
ModLoad: 000007fe`fd500000 000007fe`fd557000   C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fea90000 000007fe`feb6b000   C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fde60000 000007fe`fdeff000   C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`feb70000 000007fe`feb8f000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fdcb0000 000007fe`fddde000   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fe7f0000 000007fe`fe861000   C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`ff9b0000 000007fe`ffa17000   C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`774f0000 00000000`775ea000   C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fda40000 000007fe`fda4e000   C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fe9c0000 000007fe`fea8a000   C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`ff980000 000007fe`ff9ae000   C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
ModLoad: 000007fe`fe2e0000 000007fe`fe3e9000   C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f3cc0000 000007fe`f466e000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`75370000 00000000`75439000   C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4927_none_88dce9872fb18caf\MSVCR80.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`feb90000 000007fe`ff916000   C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fe0d0000 000007fe`fe2d2000   C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fd670000 000007fe`fd67f000   C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f27e0000 000007fe`f36bb000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\mscorlib\10e3a3015e967b69f90d58230a694f67\mscorlib.ni.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fd560000 000007fe`fd56f000   C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f2650000 000007fe`f27d4000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorjit.dll
ModLoad: 00000642`ff4a0000 00000642`ff4aa000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\culture.dll
(1870.15fc): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(1870.15fc): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(1870.15fc): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(1870.15fc): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(1870.15fc): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(1870.15fc): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
(1870.15fc): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(1870.15fc): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(1870.15fc): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(1870.15fc): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(1870.15fc): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(1870.15fc): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
ModLoad: 000007fe`f1c30000 000007fe`f264e000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System\98ac7ad6dcf7484bf8b4478ea6951cb6\System.ni.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f19f0000 000007fe`f1c27000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.Drawing\62f46b8689863e5f23b1b69fe9c92eaf\System.Drawing.ni.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f0950000 000007fe`f19e6000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.Windows.Forms\1109b73499e4e9b612bf55e2014d94df\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll
(1870.15fc): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(1870.15fc): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(1870.15fc): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(1870.15fc): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(1870.15fc): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(1870.15fc): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
(1870.15fc): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(1870.15fc): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
(1870.15fc): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (!!! second chance !!!)
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll - 
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x3d:
000007fe`fd8faa7d 4881c4c8000000  add     rsp,0C8h
```

More information:

```
0:000> |* ~* kp

.  0  Id: 198c.1874 Suspend: 1 Teb: 000007ff`fffde000 Unfrozen
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`0043a8c0 00000000`753a96d0 KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x39
00000000`0043a990 00000000`7775f001 MSVCR80!_CxxCallCatchBlock+0x180
00000000`0043aa40 000007fe`f3e721da ntdll!RcFrameConsolidation+0x3
00000000`0043e640 000007fe`f3e3543f mscorwks!MethodDesc::MakeJitWorker+0x1ea
00000000`0043e760 000007fe`f3e2702a mscorwks!MethodDesc::DoPrestub+0x116f
00000000`0043e910 000007fe`f3f8d387 mscorwks!PreStubWorker+0x1fa
00000000`0043e9d0 000007fe`f3f8d4a2 mscorwks!ThePreStubAMD64+0x87
00000000`0043eaa0 000007fe`f3e66ef3 mscorwks!CallDescrWorker+0x82
00000000`0043eaf0 000007fe`f3e56d1f mscorwks!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xd3
00000000`0043eb90 000007fe`f3ee35b7 mscorwks!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0x24f
00000000`0043ede0 000007fe`f3eff358 mscorwks!ClassLoader::RunMain+0x22b
00000000`0043f040 000007fe`f3ec7835 mscorwks!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod+0xbc
00000000`0043f330 000007fe`f3db349f mscorwks!SystemDomain::ExecuteMainMethod+0x491
00000000`0043f900 000007fe`f3ef8ab0 mscorwks!ExecuteEXE+0x47
00000000`0043f950 000007fe`f5195b21 mscorwks!CorExeMain+0xac
00000000`0043f9b0 00000000`7760f56d MSCOREE!CorExeMain_Exported+0x57
00000000`0043f9e0 00000000`77742cc1 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
00000000`0043fa10 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d

   1  Id: 198c.13f8 Suspend: 1 Teb: 000007ff`fffdc000 Unfrozen
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`020df7f8 000007fe`fd8f13a6 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xa
00000000`020df800 00000000`775ff190 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xe8
00000000`020df900 000007fe`f3f1b525 KERNEL32!WaitForMultipleObjects+0xb0
00000000`020df990 000007fe`f3efe331 mscorwks!DebuggerRCThread::MainLoop+0xbd
00000000`020dfa40 000007fe`f3db5caa mscorwks!DebuggerRCThread::ThreadProc+0xf9
00000000`020dfa90 00000000`7760f56d mscorwks!DebuggerRCThread::ThreadProcStatic+0x56
00000000`020dfae0 00000000`77742cc1 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
00000000`020dfb10 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d

   2  Id: 198c.1840 Suspend: 1 Teb: 000007ff`fffda000 Unfrozen
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`1ae1f608 000007fe`fd8f10ac ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xa
00000000`1ae1f610 000007fe`f3df72e2 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x79
00000000`1ae1f6b0 000007fe`f3df73d3 mscorwks!ZapImage::OutputDebugInfo+0xaa
00000000`1ae1f710 000007fe`f3f0f0a9 mscorwks!CLREvent::WaitEx+0x63
00000000`1ae1f7c0 000007fe`f3ef922a mscorwks!WKS::WaitForFinalizerEvent+0x49
00000000`1ae1f7f0 000007fe`f3ee4ffc mscorwks!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadWorker+0x4a
00000000`1ae1f830 000007fe`f3ea85ad mscorwks!MethodTableBuilder::AllocateFromHighFrequencyHeap+0x70
00000000`1ae1f880 000007fe`f3ef0f2d mscorwks!List<tagNgenDependents * __ptr64>::AddTail+0x11d
00000000`1ae1f950 000007fe`f3da4d1e mscorwks!ZapStubPrecode::GetType+0x39
00000000`1ae1f990 000007fe`f3eff984 mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase_NoADTransition+0x42
00000000`1ae1f9f0 000007fe`f3db0718 mscorwks!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadStart+0x74
00000000`1ae1fa30 00000000`7760f56d mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x78
00000000`1ae1fb00 00000000`77742cc1 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
00000000`1ae1fb30 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
```

Seems like when I run 'analyze', the money error file is

```
EXCEPTION_MESSAGE:  Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a
MANAGED_OBJECT_NAME:  System.IO.FileNotFoundException
MANAGED_STACK_COMMAND:  !pe 24b6010
```

But I don't understand how this could be -- .NET 3.5 is installed!

---

**I'm an idiot - I had to go enable .NET Framework 3.5.1 Features in the Features Pane of Win2008 R2 x64. I guess at least I learned a little about windbg...**

Comment: Where's the rest of the error?

Comment: Also, why can't you start the program in the debugger to start with? You could use windbg if VS can't be installed.

Comment: If you comment out the `DllImport`s and stub out those functions, does it go into `main()`?

Comment: @lnuyasha: Doesn't appear to, I still get the same KernelBase error.

Comment: I wonder if your Windows installation is borked. Also, you might check for viruses

Comment: This is what happens when you don't write an event handler for AppDomain.UnhandledException

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exception 0xE0434F4D is an unhandled CLR exception. Most likely the KERNELBASE stuff was just the library function to raise the exception - `RtlRaiseException` or similar. You'll need to either catch the exception in your CLR code, create a crash dump, or attach a debugger (such as windbg) to get details, such as a stack trace. [This MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/04/27/584927.aspx) has an example of using windbg to diagnose a CLR crash.

Comment: Added windbg output to main question description.

Comment: I'm an idiot - I had to go enable .NET Framework 3.5.1 Features in the Features Pane of Win2008 R2 x64. I guess at least I learned a little about windbg...

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered this issue in a Windows form App I created. Apparently there is a plethora of issues that can cause this. In my case you could open the Task Manager, click the application, see it open in the task manager, and immediately close. The only way to see what the issue was, was to look at the event viewer and find the error.

I had a method running in the constructor of Program.cs which is the first thing instantiated when you start a windows form app. I had a bug in code that was causing an **exception before any exception handling was created**. To fix the problem I moved the code to a point after I create an unhandled exception method as such:

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);`

in my forms constructor. Now the program would start and actually throw an error. I then just had to fix the bug in my code.

I hope this can help you or anyone else out there.

Answer (score 0):

I had a program in vb running on four machines but one.
After remote debugging I found I had a DataGridView  showing different columns on different machines. For this machine one columnname was misspelled. This caused the above error.