# Why can't NLog find my log target on Server 2008 R2?

Tags: configuration, nlog

I'm having trouble running a program that uses NLog.  I'm getting an exception during initialization that ends with:

> ---> NLogConfigurationException: Exception occurred when loading configuration ...
>   ---> System.ArgumentException: Target cannot be found: 'ColoredConsole'

I also have the [full exception text](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1561296/).

I'm fairly sure it's not a problem with my configuration, because a) I can use the same config on other machines without a problem, and b) I trimmed it down to the dumbest config I could and I still see the problem:

**NLog configuration:**

```
<configSections>
  <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
</configSections>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target name="console" xsi:type="ColoredConsole" layout="test" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I have also tried other target types, including **Console** and **File**, with the same result.

The fact that it's just this machine suggests a permission issue, but I've tried supplying permissions and administrator rights everywhere I can think of, I've tried running it as a different account and from different directories - all without any change.  The system is running Server 2008 R2, fwiw.

What might I have missed?

Comment: Does it work if you change to another target type?

Comment: Good question, but no.  (See my edit above.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server 2008 R2 comes with .NET 3.5 SP1, but it is not enabled by default.  Apparently .NET 2 *is* enabled by default, however, which is why I was able to execute some of my .NET code without receiving [a more cryptic error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498703/kernelbase-dll-error-running-c-sharp-app-on-windows-server-2008-r2).

[Enabling .NET 3.5 via the Add Features dialog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2009/08/16/you-must-use-the-role-management-tool-to-install-or-configure-microsoft-net-framework-3-5.aspx) allowed NLog to run successfully.